# Gray out checkbox but still clickable via other widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make a checkbox gray-ed out for the user, so the use can not click it but it can still be clickable via other widgets?
E.g. the user due to permissions can not click the checkbox but depending on some other combination of widgets enabled another widget can call it's click function.
Right now with the attribute `disabled` the `.click()` does not work i.e. the code does not get called. If the `disabled` is out it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but you could enable it long enough to check it, and then re-disable it:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled />

<a id="test" href="#">Click</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', 'false').prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', 'true');
    return false;
});
```

Also, just to make sure if you might not know - disabled form elements aren't included in form data.

http://jsfiddle.net/2f95y/1/

Comment: don't know why I posted my original answer the way I did, you can just do `$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);` rather than disabling and re-enabling the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/2f95y/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can bind custom event which will be called with checkbox click event and other widgets:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('input:checkbox')
  .on('myevent', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  })
  .on('click', function(){
    $(this).trigger('myevent');
  })
;

$('input:checkbox').trigger('myevent');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/643U4/

Comment: So basically the only way is to factor out the code for on click so that I can use the event mechanism?